# Is it good practice to launch Spring Application in bash screen command?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, gnu-screen

I have ready spring web application for instance. But when I upload
it to the VPS server via ftp, I can launch an application by connecting to the server via ssh. But there is a problem after exiting ssh, the application exits as well.

While googling I found some kind of solution connecting to the VPS server via `screen` in this case the application will resume even if the ssh connection is lost.

But I am very curious about if it is good solution. Could anyone launch enterprise application in such mode?

Comment: it you're using spring boot you can follow [this instruction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html) in order to install your app as a service

Comment: @eparvan How about `screen`? You can connect to it anytime you want and see how is your app doing?

Comment: you can configure spring to write your console logs into file and thus monitor your app status. Take a look [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logging-file-output).

Comment: @eparvan yes, but the question is about `screen`.

Answer (score 0):

it is about shell. if you run `java -jar yourApplication.jar`, the process is subprocess of shell. the shell quit, your application quit. use the command `nohup java -jar yourApplicaion >>/dev/null 2>&1 &`. for enterprise, they often use jenkins, Kubernetes.